# Why is this macro putting an element of a table on the wrong row?

Tags: tables, macros

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\newcommand{\macro}[2][]{%
    & something & #2 & #1 \\
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\macro{3}{4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output it produces is something along the lines of:

```
    something    3
4
```

Why is the `4` put at the beginning of a new row instead of the end of the previous row? How can I fix it?

I've already seen that putting the `\\` inside the tabular instead of the macro makes things work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\newcommand{\macro}[2][]{%
    & something & #2 & #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\macro{3}{4}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

However this isn't what I want. I'm defining a new environment that under the hood uses `tabular` but I don't want its interface to depend on putting `//` and `&` explicitly, I want them hidden inside macros.

Comment: Your are abusing it: `\macro[3]{4}` should work

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ah, I see. So when I use `\macro{3}{4}` the default argument is empty, the second argument is `3` and `{4}` is put after the macro expansion... my bad.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro `\macro` (sic!) is defined to have an optional argument. If this missing, the call `\macro{3}{4}` is the same as `\macro[]{3}` and the figure `4` will be read for the next tabular row.

The column shift in the 'wrong' usage is clearly visible. `3` is in the 4th column, instead of the requested 3rd column.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\newcommand{\macro}[2][]{%
    & something & #2 & #1 \\
}

\begin{document}
Does not work

\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\macro{3}{4}
\end{tabular}

Works

\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\macro[3]{4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want the macro without the optional argument:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\newcommand{\macro}[2]{% notice the lack of the second brackets here
    & something & #2 & #1 \\
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\macro{3}{4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's the 'safe' way, I suppose (+1)